# Grep a YAML file in Perl

Tags: perl, path, grep, yaml, hierarchy

Are there any modules in Perl which can grep an arbitrary hierarchy in a yaml file - just like ygrep in python? Or code which can do that? I tried googling but didn't find any resources/pointers for it. I have been trying since a few hours without much luck.

Answer (score 6):

[`LoadFile`](http://p3rl.org/YAML#LoadFile-filepath) returns a hash reference.

```
my $href = YAML::LoadFile("file.yaml");
```

Check CPAN for any [deep data structure traversing module](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=structures&mode=all), e.g.

- http://p3rl.org/Data::Walk
- http://p3rl.org/Data::Visitor
- http://p3rl.org/Data::Diver